# How do the NativeScript Flavor's Performance Compare? (Angular, Vue, Core)

Tags: performance, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

Can anyone share performance comparisons between the NativeScript flavors?

I'm wondering how different their speed and responsiveness is across the flavors.

Comment: NativeScript Core will obviously be the fastest but you might hate working with it if you are from Angular / Vue background. Your development time may be high as you won't have any features from these framework out of the box. It will be like opting to write a single page application from scratch when you have access to Angular / Vue. Again if you start comparing Angular vs Vue, that may be an endless debate. It's wise to choose one you are familiar and comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks @manoj ... Can you share any actual tests measuring performance?

Comment: I don't know of any performance tests like that, but really the impact of using a framework is not significant. Things like optimizing the layout do have a huge impact regardless of what flavour you choose.

Comment: @tiago absolutely, the layout choices we make have a huge impact. Have you seen this talk by Brad Martin? https://youtu.be/U191esT9_zY  ... Very insightful.

Comment: @DanielBattaglia I sure did! A couple of time, actually. 100% agree!